# How do I check if an element contains at least one direct text node

Tags: javascript, html

How do I check if an element contains **at least one direct text node** ?

Given:

```
<div id="a">
  One <span>Two</span>
</div>

<div id="b">
  <span>Three</span>
</div>

<div id="c">
  Four
</div>

<div id="d"> </div>
```

And:

```
function containsDirectText(el) {
  // using plain Javascript, not jQuery
}
```

Then:

```
containsDirectText(document.getElementById('a')) // should return true
containsDirectText(document.getElementById('b')) // should return false
containsDirectText(document.getElementById('c')) // should return true
containsDirectText(document.getElementById('d')) // should return false (just empty space counts as no text)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can check the `nodeType` of the child nodes to find text nodes, but your example "b" that you want to return `false` *does have* a text node — the spaces used to indent — so you have to exclude blank text nodes.

```js
function containsDirectText(el) {
  return [...el.childNodes]
      .some(n => n.nodeType === Node.TEXT_NODE
            && n.nodeValue.trim() !== '');
}

console.log(
containsDirectText(document.getElementById('a')) // should return true
);

console.log(
containsDirectText(document.getElementById('b')) // should return false
);

console.log(
containsDirectText(document.getElementById('c')) // should return true
);

console.log(
containsDirectText(document.getElementById('original-d')) // should return false
);

console.log(
containsDirectText(document.getElementById('new-d')) // should return false
);
```

```html
<div id="a">
  One <span>Two</span>
</div>

<div id="b">
  <span>Three</span>
</div>

<div id="c">
  Four
</div>

<div id="original-d"></div>

<div id="new-d"> </div>
```

(I split your "d" case into the original *empty* div and the updated div with only whitespace)

An element's [`childNodes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/API/Node/childNodes) returns a `NodeList`, so I use the [spread operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) to turn it into an Array, which has the [.some(callback)](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) method.

*some* returns true if the callback function returns a truthy value for at least one element in the array, so I test each element to see if its nodeType is a TEXT_NODE and that the nodeValue is not empty.

If at least one child node fits that description, *some* returns `true` so *containsDirectText* returns true.